# Is Magento a better choice than, say, OpenCart?

Tags: architecture

I've been developing non-ecommerce sites for years and I've learned is that CMS code/architecture quality, and the size of the community/ecosystem around the CMS are two essentials. For example, there are some smaller CMS's with great codebases that do very well in their specific niches. And WordPress is a perfect example of a very imperfect codebase and design, but it is supported by such a massive ecosystem of users, theme developers, plugin developers, installers and optimizers. It's hard not to find support for whatever you need.

I've worked on a couple of smaller ecommerce sites with Magento, OpenCart and some of the hosted solutions. Magento seemed overkill for the smaller site, but with a good ecosystem, and OpenCart was very light weight and it looked difficult to find off-the-shelf components for it.

There is an existing OpenCart install for this new site I'm working on - it has been configured and is working to some degree. I will not be the only developer working on this new site, but to get it off the ground it is 90% on me.

1) Is Magento the best choice for a new medium to large scale ecommerce site for me?

2) Is Magento superior to OpenCart, both in terms of code quality and architecture?

3) Are there other factors that should influence my decision for and against choosing Magento?

Answer (score 7):

I can appreciate your question. It is one that a previous company I worked at was faced with. Our choice was between OpenCart or Magento. The CTO reviewed the code base and database for both eCommerce platforms, and made a final decision. For one, he was scared off by the number of Magento tables compared to OpenCart, plus Magento's documentation wasn't as thorough as OpenCart's. So, those were his reasonings. What we ended up finding was that although OpenCart was lighter weight, and seemed to have better official documentation, OpenCart development is mainly geared for Europe. This is fine if you're outside of the U.S., but if you're U.S. based, this can cause troubles. Also, there didn't seem to be too many developers to assist with shipping modules, specifically we were having troubles with a FedEx module and lack of support. So that's what I've seen.

1. Magento is a great choice for large scaled projects. If you're using the community edition, it will take more work to fine tune the system to perform as you'd like. If you're using the enterprise edition, it has some features that you'll want already built in like full page caching. At the company I currently work at we're using community edition, and there has been quite a bit of work put into it to get it to function on an enterprise level. We've had to build our own caching ( we use Squid ), and the servers are set up with load balancers, etc. I'm not sure how some of the other offerings like Go work, so you might want to check that out too ( I'm really not sure here ).
2. Magento is an extremely well engineered eCommerce platform. It pushes what can be done via PHP, unlike any other platform in the community ( as far as I know ). The system was designed to be flexible first, and performance second. This is why some fine tuning is required, but is worth it. Because the system is so flexible, once you've learned how to work with it, it is relatively straight forward. Magento's product management blows OpenCart waay out of the water. OpenCart was such a pain to manage products. Also, OpenCart comes configured for Europe out of the box, and my company was in the U.S., so it was a pain to get things the way we needed them to be ( taxes, location, etc ). Magento's installation asks for all of this upfront which I found very refreshing.
3. Learning curve is the first thing I'd bring your attention to. Magento is very unique in a lot of ways. That being said, you'd be wise to spend some time reviewing this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand there is currently a free Fundamantals of Magento Development course. I'm currently going through it, and Ben does a great job explaining core concepts, and giving a nice top-down view of Magento. An addition to the Magento U course, check out Alan Storm ( http://alanstorm.com/category/magento and http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/ ) he's one of the most solid resources out there. The official Magento documentation could be better, so you'll need to rely on the community for help. Luckily you've come while this site has been created. The community here is trying to build this site, so you'll get feedback. Another item I'd like to revisit is fine tuning your system. Magento can be a bit heavy, so just know that you will likely need to spend some time configuring your server for performance. But there's great tools like Varnish, Memcached, etc to help with that.

I hope that I gave you some good insight! I'm a rookie, so a more advanced member will be able to offer you more.

Comment: ryanF: that's really useful, very much appreciated.

Comment: @AMcDermott you're welcome :)